# How does adding a long fixed pole on top of a drone with a certain mass change the dynamics of a quadcopter?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, aerospace-engineering

I have to model a quadcopter with a long rod on top of it so I can later design a control system for the system. I'm a bit lost as to how the dynamics of the system change by adding the rod, can someone help me out?

Comment: The rod will change the CG, the mass, and the moment of inertia. The high cg will increase the overall stability.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does it still increase stability if we consider that the forward movement of the drone is done with the drone tilted forwards. This way, the added mass on top shall generate a torque on the drone's center of mass, right?

Comment: @Drew Why would the high c.g improve the overall stability ?

Comment: @AJN, it's counterintuitive, but here's an example: the drone is stationary and rolled left, and it's applying torque through differential thrust to roll to the right. This thrust will push the drone LEFT due to the tilt. Inertia of the mass up on the pole makes it want to move RIGHT relative to the drone, thus helping the drone turn upright. If the mass is below the CG is has the opposite effect, fighting the roll action.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYHCP3-mpxk